# How to get daily result to show members?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I added a referral contest page in my site, I need to set contest date from today's date to a future date, I need to show my daily result to members, my code is below

```
$my_time = time() - 5184000;

$top10 = $db->query("SELECT m2.username, count(*) as referrals FROM users m1 inner join users m2 on m1.ref=m2.id where m1.reg_time <= $my_time group by m1.ref, m2.username ORDER BY `referrals` DESC LIMIT 10");

<div class="box">
        <div class="info_box">Top 10 referrers in last 60 days</div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr><th>Username</th><th>Total Referrals</th></tr>
                                <?php if (count($top10) > 0) {

                while($row = $top10->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>{$row['username']}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$row['referrals']}</td>"; 
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }

            ?>


        </table>


    </div>
```

But this code give me only this result:

[image]

How can i set result starting from today and ends in a future date?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CURDATE();` will give you the current date.

As for the future date, are you using a table to determine this value or are you setting it through an input on the page?